# Laravel - Email queued doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have an application that send several email, sometimes it returns me a timeout error. So I think the solution for that is sending the emails in background with queued but I'm having problems to implement that.

For example in my controller I have that and works:

```
$data = array(
            'name' => $tecnic->name,
            'email' => $tecnic->email,
            'code' => $code
          );
Mail::send('email-to-tecnico', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
          $message->from('no-reply@domain.pt' , 'Title');
          $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('subject');

        });
```

Next I create a `Job SendStartPatEmail` and add this:

```
use Mail;
class SendStartPatEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $data;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
      $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
      Mail::send('email-to-tecnico', $data, function($message) use ($data)
      {
        $message->from('no-reply@domain.pt' , 'Title');

        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Subject');

      });
    }
}
```

And in controller I remove Mail::send and add this:

```
SendStartPatEmail::dispatch($data);
```

When I run this the job was created in job table but don't send the email and the attempts column is 0 .

This don't return any error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check your logs what kind of errors you are getting

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I don't have any error in log file

Comment: are you runing `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz Ok if I run php artisan queue:work I have this error in logo files: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the queued jobs in the jobs table, you need to run `php artisan queue:work`.

I recommend reading the documentation regarding supervisor to make sure the worker always runs on projects where you need it:

[Laravel Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Comment: Ok if I run php artisan queue:work I have this error in logo files: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: data'

Comment: Well, thats a different issue to the one your question is about. Obviously, the variable $data is undefined in your code. The error also probably refers to what line, in which file where data is undefined.

Comment: Is at handle() in Job @OleHaugset

Comment: this line Mail::send('email-to-tecnico', $data, function($message) use ($data) @OleHaugset

Comment: yes, thats because you haven't defined $data. It's $this->data since data now is a property of the class.

Comment: Ok. Works now. How can I execute a job automatically? @OleHaugset

Comment: Read my answer. I linked it to you. And since my answer solved your problem, you should accept it as the correct one.